# servlet clear local storage

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, local-storage

How the servlet can clear localStorage? I try the following code, but it does not clear the localStorage data. When user logout account, it will direct to logout.java servlet, destroy session object and clear localStorage:

```
    / ... /
    request.logout();
    request.getSession().invalidate();
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("student");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    out.println("localStorage.clear();");
    out.println("</script>");
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    /..../
```

Is there any error?

Answer (score 1):

you are calling `response.sendRedirect()` which sends to the browser an HTTP 302 response code and a `Location` HTTP header.  Your browser is almost certainly ignoring any message body written to the response, so your script will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code that you are closing tag

```
out.println("</javascript>");
```

Is the issue.
You have opened `<script>` so that close it `</script>`.

Comment: @helloworld1234 do you put script tag inside head or body of your html?

Comment: Make sure your html document is built completely containing html, body and head tag and make sure <!DOCTYPE html> is on top of your document. I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thx a lot, I’ve debugged my problems...another issue cause the problems.